# Ecto WHERE IN subquery

Tags: sql, subquery, elixir, ecto

This is my subquery (it will always return one record due to the where clause):

```
subset = 
from(a in "table1", where: a. id == ^parameter, select: [a.special_id1, a.special_id2, a.special_id3])
```

This is my main query:

```
from(b in "table2", where: b.id in subquery(subset), select: [:first_name, :last_name]
```

Getting this error:

> ** (Ecto.QueryError) subquery must return a single field in order to be used on the right-side of `in` in query:

I understand why, the subquery would return a structure like this `[[special_id1, special_id2...]]`. I want the subquery to return just a flat list. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot. However you can use `exists/1` query with subquery that will match on parent field:

```
subset = 
  from(a in "table1",
    where: a.id == ^parameter,
    where: parent_as(:table2).id in [a.special_id1, a.special_id2, a.special_id3],
    select: 1)

from(b in "table2", as: :table2,
  where: exists(subquery(subset)),
  select: [:first_name, :last_name])
```

That should provide you the query you are looking for.